# How can I SELECT the groups in a query with more than one item in them?

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, group-by

I'm pretty new to SQL, and I'm trying to do something like this:

I have a tabled called `Foo` with two columns in it: `FooId` (the primary key) and `BarId` (a non-nullable foreign key that can have duplicate values in it).

I want to write a query that returns the `BarId`s that only appear once in `Foo`. I also want to write another query that returns the `BarId`s that appear more than once in `Foo`.

I started with something like this:

```
SELECT
    BarId,
    COUNT(BarId) AS "BarCount"
    FROM [Database].[dbo].[Foo]
    GROUP BY BarId
```

Which returns the number of occurrences of each `BarId`. But as soon as I try to add a `WHERE` clause, I get a syntax error:

```
SELECT
    BarId,
    COUNT(BarId) AS "BarCount"
    FROM [Database].[dbo].[Foo]
    GROUP BY BarId
    WHERE "BarCount" > 1
```

I'm sure this is some silly mistake that I am making by not understanding SQL very well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used with aggregates, you need to use a `HAVING` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    BarId,
    COUNT(BarId) AS "BarCount"
    FROM [Database].[dbo].[Foo]
    GROUP BY BarId
    HAVING COUNT(BarID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `HAVING` clause.  It's like a `WHERE` for aggregate functions.  See [This overview.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)